# How to understand and mitigate the local privilege escalation vulnerability on Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, security

According to [CVE.MITRE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-9644), there are a several security issues on the linux kernel `4.4.x`, there is the discription:

> The __get_user_asm_ex macro in arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h in the Linux kernel 4.4.22 through 4.4.28 contains extended asm statements that are incompatible with the exception table, which allows local users to obtain root access on non-SMEP platforms via a crafted application. NOTE: this vulnerability exists because of incorrect backporting of the CVE-2016-9178 patch to older kernels.

The vulnerability affects:

```
Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS
Ubuntu Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS
Linux kernel 4.4.29
Linux kernel 4.4.28
Linux kernel 4.4.27
Linux kernel 4.4.25
Linux kernel 4.4.24
```

How to easily understand and patch the local privilege escalation on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just apply system updates regularly, especially those marked as security updates. Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS comes with kernel 4.4.0-31 (which is already newer that 4.4.0-29, the last kernel version to have this vulnerability), and currently (3-Dec-2016) the kernel for 16.04 is at 4.4.0-51.